# What is the probability the the second toss is heads?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

One bag contains two coins. One is fair, the other is biased with Heads probability = $0.6$. One coin is randomly picked and it is tossed. It lands heads up. What is the probability that the same coin will land heads up if tossed again?

Now, the probability that for a coin randomly picked up the toss will result in a head is given by the formula for total probability. Writing $B_1, B_2$ the events that the fair coin and the biased coin is selected, respectively and $E_1$ the event that the coin will land heads up in the first toss, we obtain
$$
P(E_1) = P(E_1|B_1)P(B_1)  + P(E_1|B_2)P(B_2) = 0.5\cdot0.5 + 0.6\cdot0.5 = 11/20.
$$
However, it is not clear to me how to calculate now the probability $P(E_2)$. I would like to use again the total probability formula for $E_2$, i.e.,
$$
P(E_2) = P(E_2|E_1)P(E_1)  + P(E_2|E_1^c)P(E_1^c) = P(E_2|E_1)\cdot 11/20 + P(E_2|E_1^c)\cdot 9/20
$$
But I don't see how to calculate $P(E_2|E_1), \  P(E_2|E_1^c)$. So in the end I suspect that my method doesn't work and a better solution should be given.

Comment: If you know the probability that the fair coin was selected, the rest is easy. Could you calculate this ?

Comment: @Peter Sorry but I don't find your comment particularly clear. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next you need to use bayes theorem to figure out the posterior probability $P(B_1|E_1)$ that the coin picked is fair
$$P(B_1|E_1)=\frac {P(E_1|B_1)P(B_1)}{P(E_1)}=\frac {0.5 \cdot 0.5}{11/20} = 5/11$$

To determine the probability of $E_2$ given $E_1$
$$P(E_2|E_1) = P(E_2 B_1|E_1) + P(E_2 B_1^c|E_1) = P(E_2|B_1 E_1)P(B_1|E_1)  + P(E_2|B_1^c E_1)P(B_1^c|E_1) $$
Using the fact that flips of the same coin are independent, $P(E_2|B_1 E_1)=P(E_2|B_1)=0.5$ and $P(E_2|B_1^c E_1)=P(E_2|B_1^c)=0.6$, and substituting these probabilities in gives
$$P(E_2|E_1) = P(E_2|B_1)P(B_1|E_1)  + P(E_2|B_1^c)P(B_1^c|E_1) = .5 \cdot 5/11 + .6 \cdot 6/11$$

Comment: Thank you, very good explanation. However, I don't see why the last relation, $P(E_2|E_1) = P(E_2|B_1)P(B_1|E_1)  + P(E_2|B_1^c)P(B_1^c|E_1)$ is true?

Comment: If you didn't know that $E_1$ was true, you would have $P(E_2) = P(E_2|B_1)P(B_1)  + P(E_2|B_1^c)P(B_1^c)$, which is like the equation you used to determine the prior probability of $É_1$.Then you just add "given $E_1$" to all the terms.

Comment: Or approached from a different direction, it's breaking $P(E_2|E_1)$ into the cases $P(E_2 \& B_1|E_1)$ and $P(E_2 \& B_1^c|E_1)$

Comment: Wait a minute: we certainly have $P(E_2B_1 |E_1)  = P(E_2 |B_1E_1)P(B_1|E_1)$, but why this should be equal to $P(E_2 |B_1)P(B_1|E_1)$, i.e. why $P(E_2 |B_1E_1) = P(E_2 |B_1)$ as you claim, is not clear at all. I even doubt it's true. Can you write a proof?

Comment: It's not a mathematical invariant, it's part of the problem description. We're told a value of $P(E_2|B_1)=0.5$, and that value is independent of $E_1$, because that's how coins work; two flips are independent trials, so $P(E_2|B_1)=P(E_2|B_1 E_1)=P(E_2|B_1 E_1^c)$. If you have a fair coin, and it previously landed heads, you have a 50% chance it'll land heads again. If instead you have a fair coin, and it previously landed tails, you still have a 50% chance it'll land heads on the next flip.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, $P(E_2 |B_1$ ) equals $P(E_2 |B_1E_1)$ because the probabilty of getting H tossing a fair coin in the second trial is the same as the probability of getting H "given that in the first trial" we got also H, since of course two trials with the same fair coin are independent. I got your point. Is it there some precise way to express this in terms of events?  I mean does it make sense of talking of the "event $E_2 |B_1$ having the same probability of the event $E_2 |B_1E_1$?

Comment: I don't think the original question is asking $P(E_2|E_1)$. $P(E_2|E_1)$ means given the first coin is heads up, what is the probability of heads up again. However, in the original question, it also requires we are tossing the SAME coin.